# How to add another column in the text file?

Tags: python-2.7, twitter, dataset

I have made a text file which has words and their occurrences in a tweet.
The text file looks like

```
W1 W2 W2 ..
1  0  0  ..
```

where W1= word 1
I want to add another column after the Wn which be the time the tweet was extracted. I have the time in another text file.

My Code:

```
df = pd.read_csv('Twidb11.csv',error_bad_lines=False, sep='delimiter',  engine='python')
# Creating Bag of Words
count_vect = CountVectorizer()
X_train_counts = count_vect.fit_transform(df.Text)
freq_matrix = count_vect.fit_transform(df.Text).todense()
#print type(freq_matrix)
#X_train_counts.shape 
words = count_vect.vocabulary_
sorted_words = sorted(words.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))
print sorted_words

for key, value in sorted_words:
    saveFile8 = open('Twidb14.txt', 'a')#bag of words their occurences
    saveThis8 = key
    saveFile8.write(saveThis8)
    saveFile8.write('   ')
    saveFile8.close()
    print key

saveFile8 = open('Twidb14.txt', 'a')
saveFile8.write('\n')
freq_matrix.tofile(saveFile8, sep=" ", format="%s")
saveFile8.close()
```

I want to include the column of time and also the time.

Comment: I believe you to read both the files and write the data to a new file to get the time column

Comment: Ty, but is there no way I can append the time column to the current text file?

Comment: You can write to the existing file, but it's essentially the same as writing it to a new file.

Comment: Any source or sample code available?

Comment: I assumed how both the files looked from the question and took a swing at it. Check it out https://gist.github.com/yash1th/73b76817d239295a31c79a2b0fc2aae9

Comment: This one is editing the existing file. Check out https://gist.github.com/yash1th/d04e13281c2245e409ff1b7c048ce30c , Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: this helped but I used izip_longest

Comment: Good. It has been renamed to `zip_longest` in `python3.x`